# /statuses/update.json - error 32 when including 'æ' in the status

Tags: json, twitter, unicode, oauth, emoji

REST API .NET 4.5 Backend Application with Callback URL.

Just to state a few things I have already done...

1. Verified base signature string against twitter oauth tester
2. Tried all 3rd party repo's including Linq2Twitter, TweetSharp, etc.
3. Verified that 2 byte unicode characters are being properly encoded and match exactly what twitter generates via the oauth tester.

My application crossposting (per user basis) works fine, to Twitter. The problem is only reproducable when including unreserved characters and emoji. Does anyone have any real experience solving this exact problem?

Comment: Have you tried URL encoding the string? Hard to tell what you've tried without seeing any code.

Comment: Yes, and I finally solved the issue. I will post my changes to the the encoder, http, and oauth in .NET framework for anyone else that has this problem. Thank you for responding.

Comment: hi have the same issue with emoticon, this must be related. Could you explain how you fixed this ?

Comment: here is my error message: 11-30 01:48:26.863: D/SocialAuthError(10470): org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: Failed to update status on https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=hello%F0%9F%98%81ok. Status :401 Error Message : {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}
11-30 01:48:26.863: D/ShareTwitter(10470): Authentication Error: Message Not Posted

Answer (score 0):

Http.CS
Comment out the following...

```
//headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-us,en;q=0.5";
//headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip,deflate";
//headers["Accept-Charset"] = "utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
```

UrlEncoder.cs

```
public static string UrlEncode(string value)
    {
        const string ReservedChars = @"`!@#$%^&*()_-+=.~,:;'?/|\[] ";
        const string UnReservedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_.~";

        var result = new StringBuilder();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            return string.Empty;

        foreach (string symbol in value.AsCodePoints())
        {
            if (symbol.Length == 1 && UnReservedChars.IndexOf(symbol, StringComparison.CurrentCulture) != -1)
            {
                result.Append(symbol);
            }
            else if (symbol.Length == 1 && ReservedChars.IndexOf(symbol, StringComparison.CurrentCulture) != -1)
            {
                result.Append('%' + String.Format("{0:X2}", (int)symbol.ToCharArray().First()).ToUpper());
            }
            else
            {
                string symbolString = symbol;
                var encoded = Uri.EscapeDataString(symbolString).ToUpper();

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(encoded))
                {
                    result.Append(encoded);
                }
            }
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Nothing changed with OAUTH. It was all about the Encoding of the characters.